# pyinstaller fails to build a .exe

Tags: pyinstaller

I'm trying to make an .exe from my python script using pyinstaller. When I call pyinstaller, the process completes, but with many flags along the way. Some don't seem essential but it is hard for me to tell. I am using python 3.5 on an OSX machine but trying to make an .exe

```
    55 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.1.1
55 INFO: Python: 3.5.1
60 INFO: Platform: Darwin-15.4.0-x86_64-i386-64bit
61 INFO: wrote /Users/kumars01/vectorgithub/pacer.spec
63 INFO: UPX is not available.
65 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['/Users/kumars01/vectorgithub', '/Users/kumars01/vectorgithub']
65 INFO: checking Analysis
65 INFO: Building Analysis because out00-Analysis.toc is non existent
65 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
67 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
68 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
3009 INFO: running Analysis out00-Analysis.toc
3017 INFO: Analyzing /Users/kumars01/vectorgithub/pacer.py
3118 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   distutils
3328 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   six.moves
7094 INFO: Processing pre-find module path hook   site
7095 INFO: site: retargeting to fake-dir '/Users/kumars01/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyInstaller/fake-modules'
7117 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   win32com
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'win32com'
7163 INFO: Processing pre-safe import module hook   win32com
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'win32com'
45859 INFO: Looking for import hooks ...
45862 INFO: Processing hook   hook-distutils.py
45863 INFO: Processing hook   hook-sqlite3.py
45866 INFO: Processing hook   hook-scipy.special._ufuncs.py
45866 INFO: Processing hook   hook-docutils.py
46277 INFO: Processing hook   hook-scipy.sparse.csgraph.py
46280 INFO: Processing hook   hook-matplotlib.backends.py
47073 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTK": ignored
    Gtk* backend requires pygtk to be installed.
47621 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTKAgg": ignored
    Gtk* backend requires pygtk to be installed.
48013 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTKCairo": ignored
    No module named 'gtk'
48607 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "MacOSX": added
49232 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "Qt4Agg": added
49849 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "Qt5Agg": added
50417 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "TkAgg": added
50962 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WX": ignored
    Matplotlib backend_wx and backend_wxagg require wxPython >=2.8.12
51513 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WXAgg": ignored
    Matplotlib backend_wx and backend_wxagg require wxPython >=2.8.12
51906 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "CocoaAgg": ignored
    The CococaAgg backend required PyObjC to be installed!
52307 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTK3Cairo": ignored
    Gtk3 backend requires pygobject to be installed.
52851 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "GTK3Agg": ignored
    Gtk3 backend requires pygobject to be installed.
53277 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "WebAgg": ignored
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 12, in <module>
  File "/Users/kumars01/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_webagg.py", line 32, in <module>
    import tornado.web
  File "/Users/kumars01/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 82, in <module>
    from tornado.concurrent import Future
  File "/Users/kumars01/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 37, in <module>
    from concurrent import futures
  File "/Users/kumars01/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/concurrent/futures/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from concurrent.futures._base import (FIRST_COMPLETED,
  File "/Users/kumars01/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 355
    raise type(self._exception), self._exception, self._traceback
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
53696 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "nbAgg": ignored
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 12, in <module>
  File "/Users/kumars01/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_nbagg.py", line 14, in <module>
    import tornado.ioloop
  File "/Users/kumars01/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 46, in <module>
    from tornado.concurrent import TracebackFuture, is_future
  File "/Users/kumars01/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 37, in <module>
    from concurrent import futures
  File "/Users/kumars01/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/concurrent/futures/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from concurrent.futures._base import (FIRST_COMPLETED,
  File "/Users/kumars01/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/concurrent/futures/_base.py", line 355
    raise type(self._exception), self._exception, self._traceback
                               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
54244 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "agg": added
54646 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "cairo": ignored
    Cairo backend requires that cairocffi or pycairo is installed.
55039 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "emf": ignored
    No module named 'matplotlib.backends.backend_emf'
55440 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "gdk": ignored
    No module named 'gobject'
55987 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "pdf": added
/Users/kumars01/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_pgf.py:54: UserWarning: error getting fonts from fc-list
  warnings.warn('error getting fonts from fc-list', UserWarning)
56555 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "pgf": added
57104 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "ps": added
57663 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "svg": added
58203 INFO:   Matplotlib backend "template": added
58543 INFO: Processing hook   hook-PyQt4.py
58776 ERROR: Cannot find qt_menu.nib directory
58786 INFO: Processing hook   hook-lxml.etree.py
58795 INFO: Processing hook   hook-cryptography.py
58798 INFO: Processing hook   hook-PyQt4.QtCore.py
58881 INFO: Processing hook   hook-pkg_resources.py
58882 INFO: Processing hook   hook-xml.dom.domreg.py
58882 INFO: Processing hook   hook-zmq.py
59555 INFO: Excluding import 'zmq.libzmq'
59564 WARNING:   From zmq removing import zmq.libzmq
59567 INFO: Processing hook   hook-xml.py
59567 INFO: Processing hook   hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py
59568 INFO: Processing hook   hook-babel.py
59613 INFO: Processing hook   hook-jinja2.py
59631 INFO: Processing hook   hook-sphinx.py
62459 INFO: Processing hook   hook-boto.py
62467 INFO: Processing hook   hook-pygments.py
63764 INFO: Processing hook   hook-shelve.py
63772 INFO: Processing hook   hook-PyQt4.QtGui.py
64119 INFO: Processing hook   hook-pycparser.py
64372 INFO: Processing hook   hook-scipy.io.matlab.py
64373 INFO: Processing hook   hook-scipy.linalg.py
64374 INFO: Processing hook   hook-encodings.py
64385 INFO: Processing hook   hook-patsy.py
64386 INFO: Processing hook   hook-sqlalchemy.py
64590 WARNING: Hidden import 'MySQLdb' not found (probably old hook)
64591 INFO: Processing hook   hook-PIL.py
64612 INFO: Excluding import 'PyQt4'
64624 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PyQt4.QtGui.QImage
64624 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PyQt4.QtGui.QPixmap
64624 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PyQt4.QtGui
64624 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PyQt4.QtCore.QBuffer
64624 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PyQt4.QtCore
64624 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PyQt4.QtCore.QIODevice
64625 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PyQt4.QtGui.qRgba
64626 INFO: Excluding import 'PySide'
64638 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PySide
64638 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PySide.QImage
64638 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PySide.qRgba
64638 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PySide.QPixmap
64639 INFO: Excluding import 'PyQt5'
64651 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PyQt5.QImage
64652 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PyQt5.QPixmap
64652 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PyQt5
64652 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageQt removing import PyQt5.qRgba
64653 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'FixTk'
64653 INFO: Excluding import 'tkinter'
64663 WARNING:   From PIL.ImageTk removing import tkinter
64664 INFO: Processing hook   hook-IPython.py
66079 INFO: Processing hook   hook-gevent.monkey.py
66084 INFO: Processing hook   hook-matplotlib.py
66513 INFO: Processing hook   hook-setuptools.py
66515 INFO: Processing hook   hook-requests.py
66517 INFO: Processing hook   hook-_tkinter.py
66636 INFO: checking Tree
66637 INFO: Building Tree because out00-Tree.toc is non existent
66637 INFO: Building Tree out00-Tree.toc
66649 INFO: checking Tree
66649 INFO: Building Tree because out01-Tree.toc is non existent
66649 INFO: Building Tree out01-Tree.toc
66658 INFO: Processing hook   hook-jsonschema.py
66659 INFO: Processing hook   hook-PIL.Image.py
66849 INFO: Processing hook   hook-pydoc.py
66849 INFO: Processing hook   hook-PyQt4.QtSvg.py
66850 INFO: Processing hook   hook-sysconfig.py
66851 INFO: Processing hook   hook-pytz.py
66888 INFO: Processing hook   hook-tables.py
66889 INFO: Processing hook   hook-idlelib.py
66894 INFO: Processing hook   hook-PIL.SpiderImagePlugin.py
66915 INFO: Import to be excluded not found: 'FixTk'
66915 INFO: Excluding import 'tkinter'
67097 INFO: checking Tree
67097 INFO: Building Tree because out02-Tree.toc is non existent
67097 INFO: Building Tree out02-Tree.toc
67207 INFO: checking Tree
67208 INFO: Building Tree because out03-Tree.toc is non existent
67208 INFO: Building Tree out03-Tree.toc
67209 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
67270 WARNING: library user32 required via ctypes not found
67316 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
67391 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_pkgres.py'
67394 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth__tkinter.py'
67397 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_qt4plugins.py'
67400 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_mplconfig.py'
67402 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_mpldata.py'
67541 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
67548 ERROR: Can not find path ./libQtCore.4.dylib (needed by /Users/kumars01/anaconda/plugins/codecs/libqkrcodecs.dylib)
67552 ERROR: Can not find path /usr/local/lib/libjpeg.8.dylib (needed by /Users/kumars01/anaconda/plugins/imageformats/libqjpeg.dylib)
67552 ERROR: Can not find path ./libQtCore.4.dylib (needed by /Users/kumars01/anaconda/plugins/imageformats/libqjpeg.dylib)
67552 ERROR: Can not find path ./libQtGui.4.dylib (needed by /Users/kumars01/anaconda/plugins/imageformats/libqjpeg.dylib)
67555 ERROR: Can not find path ./libQtGui.4.dylib (needed by /Users/kumars01/anaconda/plugins/imageformats/libqtga.dylib)
67555 ERROR: Can not find path ./libQtCore.4.dylib (needed by /Users/kumars01/anaconda/plugins/imageformats/libqtga.dylib)
67557 ERROR: Can not find path ./libQtGui.4.dylib (needed by /Users/kumars01/anaconda/plugins/accessible/libqtaccessiblewidgets.dylib)
67557 ERROR: Can not find path ./libQtCore.4.dylib (needed by /Users/kumars01/anaconda/plugins/accessible/libqtaccessiblewidgets.dylib)
67561 ERROR: Can not find path ./libQtCore.4.dylib (needed by /Users/kumars01/anaconda/plugins/codecs/libqjpcodecs.dylib)
67563 ERROR: Can not find path ./libQtGui.4.dylib (needed by /Users/kumars01/anaconda/plugins/imageformats/libqgif.dylib)
67563 ERROR: Can not find path ./libQtCore.4.dylib (needed by /Users/kumars01/anaconda/plugins/imageformats/libqgif.dylib)
67565 ERROR: Can not find path ./libQtXml.4.dylib (needed by /Users/kumars01/anaconda/plugins/imageformats/libqsvg.dylib)
67565 ERROR: Can not find path ./libQtCore.4.dylib (needed by /Users/kumars01/anaconda/plugins/imageformats/libqsvg.dylib)
67565 ERROR: Can not find path ./libQtGui.4.dylib (needed by /Users/kumars01/anaconda/plugins/imageformats/libqsvg.dylib)
67565 ERROR: Can not find path ./libQtSvg.4.dylib (needed by /Users/kumars01/anaconda/plugins/imageformats/libqsvg.dylib)
67567 ERROR: Can not find path ./libQtGui.4.dylib (needed by /Users/kumars01/anaconda/plugins/imageformats/libqico.dylib)
67568 ERROR: Can not find path ./libQtCore.4.dylib (needed by /Users/kumars01/anaconda/plugins/imageformats/libqico.dylib)
67570 ERROR: Can not find path ./libz.1.dylib (needed by /Users/kumars01/anaconda/plugins/imageformats/libqtiff.dylib)
67570 ERROR: Can not find path ./libQtCore.4.dylib (needed by /Users/kumars01/anaconda/plugins/imageformats/libqtiff.dylib)
67570 ERROR: Can not find path ./libQtGui.4.dylib (needed by /Users/kumars01/anaconda/plugins/imageformats/libqtiff.dylib)
67572 ERROR: Can not find path ./libQtCore.4.dylib (needed by /Users/kumars01/anaconda/plugins/graphicssystems/libqglgraphicssystem.dylib)
67573 ERROR: Can not find path ./libQtGui.4.dylib (needed by /Users/kumars01/anaconda/plugins/graphicssystems/libqglgraphicssystem.dylib)
67573 ERROR: Can not find path ./libQtOpenGL.4.dylib (needed by /Users/kumars01/anaconda/plugins/graphicssystems/libqglgraphicssystem.dylib)
67575 ERROR: Can not find path ./libQtCore.4.dylib (needed by /Users/kumars01/anaconda/plugins/graphicssystems/libqtracegraphicssystem.dylib)
67575 ERROR: Can not find path ./libQtGui.4.dylib (needed by /Users/kumars01/anaconda/plugins/graphicssystems/libqtracegraphicssystem.dylib)
67575 ERROR: Can not find path ./libQtNetwork.4.dylib (needed by /Users/kumars01/anaconda/plugins/graphicssystems/libqtracegraphicssystem.dylib)
67580 ERROR: Can not find path ./libQtCore.4.dylib (needed by /Users/kumars01/anaconda/plugins/codecs/libqcncodecs.dylib)
67584 ERROR: Can not find path ./libz.1.dylib (needed by /Users/kumars01/anaconda/plugins/imageformats/libqmng.dylib)
67584 ERROR: Can not find path ./libQtCore.4.dylib (needed by /Users/kumars01/anaconda/plugins/imageformats/libqmng.dylib)
67584 ERROR: Can not find path ./libQtGui.4.dylib (needed by /Users/kumars01/anaconda/plugins/imageformats/libqmng.dylib)
67588 ERROR: Can not find path ./libQtXml.4.dylib (needed by /Users/kumars01/anaconda/plugins/iconengines/libqsvgicon.dylib)
67588 ERROR: Can not find path ./libQtCore.4.dylib (needed by /Users/kumars01/anaconda/plugins/iconengines/libqsvgicon.dylib)
67588 ERROR: Can not find path ./libQtGui.4.dylib (needed by /Users/kumars01/anaconda/plugins/iconengines/libqsvgicon.dylib)
67589 ERROR: Can not find path ./libQtSvg.4.dylib (needed by /Users/kumars01/anaconda/plugins/iconengines/libqsvgicon.dylib)
67591 ERROR: Can not find path ./libQtCore.4.dylib (needed by /Users/kumars01/anaconda/plugins/codecs/libqtwcodecs.dylib)
67596 ERROR: Can not find path ././libQtCore.4.dylib (needed by /Users/kumars01/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt4/QtCore.so)
67600 ERROR: Can not find path ././libQtGui.4.dylib (needed by /Users/kumars01/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt4/QtSvg.so)
67600 ERROR: Can not find path ././libQtSvg.4.dylib (needed by /Users/kumars01/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt4/QtSvg.so)
67600 ERROR: Can not find path ././libQtCore.4.dylib (needed by /Users/kumars01/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt4/QtSvg.so)
67608 ERROR: Can not find path ././libQtGui.4.dylib (needed by /Users/kumars01/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt4/QtGui.so)
67608 ERROR: Can not find path ././libQtCore.4.dylib (needed by /Users/kumars01/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyQt4/QtGui.so)
67757 ERROR: Can not find path ./libfreetype.6.dylib (needed by /Users/kumars01/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/ft2font.cpython-35m-darwin.so)
67758 ERROR: Can not find path ./libz.1.dylib (needed by /Users/kumars01/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/ft2font.cpython-35m-darwin.so)
67759 ERROR: Can not find path ./libpng16.16.dylib (needed by /Users/kumars01/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/_png.cpython-35m-darwin.so)
67766 ERROR: Can not find path ./libfreetype.6.dylib (needed by /Users/kumars01/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/_backend_agg.cpython-35m-darwin.so)
67766 ERROR: Can not find path ./libz.1.dylib (needed by /Users/kumars01/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/_backend_agg.cpython-35m-darwin.so)
67770 ERROR: Can not find path ./libtcl8.5.dylib (needed by /Users/kumars01/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/_tkagg.cpython-35m-darwin.so)
67770 ERROR: Can not find path ./libtk8.5.dylib (needed by /Users/kumars01/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/_tkagg.cpython-35m-darwin.so)
67946 ERROR: Can not find path ././libhdf5.10.dylib (needed by /Users/kumars01/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tables/_comp_bzip2.so)
67959 ERROR: Can not find path ././libhdf5.10.dylib (needed by /Users/kumars01/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tables/indexesextension.so)
67961 ERROR: Can not find path ././libhdf5.10.dylib (needed by /Users/kumars01/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tables/tableextension.so)
67963 ERROR: Can not find path ././libhdf5.10.dylib (needed by /Users/kumars01/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tables/linkextension.so)
67965 ERROR: Can not find path ././libhdf5.10.dylib (needed by /Users/kumars01/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tables/hdf5extension.so)
67967 ERROR: Can not find path ././libhdf5.10.dylib (needed by /Users/kumars01/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tables/utilsextension.so)
68220 INFO: Looking for eggs
68220 INFO: Python library not in binary depedencies. Doing additional searching...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/kumars01/anaconda/bin/pyinstaller", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(run())
  File "/Users/kumars01/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 90, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "/Users/kumars01/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyInstaller/__main__.py", line 46, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/kumars01/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 755, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "/Users/kumars01/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 701, in build
    exec(text, spec_namespace)
  File "<string>", line 16, in <module>
  File "/Users/kumars01/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 212, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "/Users/kumars01/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/datastruct.py", line 183, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "/Users/kumars01/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 510, in assemble
    self._check_python_library(self.binaries)
  File "/Users/kumars01/anaconda/lib/python3.5/site-packages/PyInstaller/building/build_main.py", line 593, in _check_python_library
    raise IOError(msg)
OSError: Python library not found: .Python, libpython3.5.dylib, Python
This would mean your Python installation doesn't come with proper library files.
This usually happens by missing development package, or unsuitable build parameters of Python installation.

* On Debian/Ubuntu, you would need to install Python development packages
  * apt-get install python3-dev
  * apt-get install python-dev
* If you're building Python by yourself, please rebuild your Python with `--enable-shared` (or, `--enable-framework` on Darwin)
```

Comment: Were you able to find an answer to this question? I'm running into the same issue

Comment: @user772401 Well I ended up not needing to make .exe's after all, only developing for Macs.  I am still digging deep on pyinstaller, lots of quirks when i import modules...

Answer (score 0):

I was wondering have you tried [pyinstaller gui](http://santiagoit.com/pyinstallergui/). It seems to solve some problems.

Comment: Instead of posting links as answer add some text to explanation how this answer help to OP in fixing current issue.Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the advice @ρяσѕρєяK, do you have a solution in mind?